# Do you know the angles of a face for a 7 or 14 sided die?

Tags: dice

I need a 5 and 7 sided mathematically fair die. The 10 sided die could replace the D5 (If you're wondering the angles are nearly 52°, 128° and two 90° opposites from each other), but I couldn't find a way to make a perfect D7 or the angles for a perfect D14.

Analyzing the D10 and D8 there are 3 properties

- Have a circumsphere,
- All faces must be congruent and
- Opposites sides must be parallel

I don't like the idea for using a D8, with the 8 meaning '*Roll again*' so don´t answer with that or similar answers.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! So are you looking for angles for [Die #1](https://www.thediceshoponline.com/gamescience-gem-amethyst-d14-dice) or [Die #2](https://www.thediceshoponline.com/gamescience-permafrost-d14-dice)? Or both? And… um… why? Do you plan to custom print something? Anyway, thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: What exactly are you going to do?  There are free STL files for d14 that seem to meet your requirements. Do you need angles to model your own?  Why can't you use the ones that are out there?

Comment: Your discussion of kites' angles suggests a trapezohedral d14. Is there any reason a high H:R heptagonal prism wouldn't meet your needs? (In which case the angles are trivial.) I mean, there's your unexplained requirement that opposite sides must be parallel... but the same question would stand for a high H:R 14-gonal prism.

Comment: Related meta discussion: [Should questions about dice in general be on topic? 2023](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12516/62294)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because the geometric construction of a die is not on topic for RPG.SE and does not relate to RPG expertise.

Answer (score 9):

### d14

According to [this MathExchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1325574/1035142), the faces of any such trapezohedron will have two 90-degree angles opposite from each other. The angle \$\theta\$ at the pole vertex is given by

$$
\tan \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{a}{b} = \sqrt{\tan{\frac{\pi}{n}} \tan{\frac{\pi}{2n}}}
$$

where the die has \$2n\$ faces and \$a\$ and \$b\$ are the side lengths. For \$n = 7\$ this comes out to about 36.68 degrees, which makes the "tropical" angle about 143.32 degrees.

See also [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114672/72732) for d10s.

### d7

Attempts at a die with 7 (rollable) faces include:

- Pentagonal prism with tuned aspect ratio, e.g. [the ones by GameScience analyzed in a previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123545/is-gamesciences-non-cylindrical-seven-sided-die-a-balanced-fair-die).
- Spacing 7 points as widely as possible on a sphere and then flattening the sphere at each such point, e.g. [Goodman Games' *Dungeon Crawl Classics* dice](https://goodman-games.com/store/product/dcc-special-7-dice-set/).
- [Long dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_dice) that are unstable on their ends. [Teetotums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teetotum) are similar.

Some of these are harder to make fair under different rolling conditions/techniques, and for the most part they do not have a level top face when laid on a table.